# How to display random image from random directory

Tags: php, image, random, directory

Im trying to select random image from random directory. I make function to get random directory and another function to get random image from that directory. Okay, but its not working, its getting random directory **and random image from another directory**

```
<?php

function showRandomDir()
    {
    $files = glob('images/portfolio/*/', GLOB_ONLYDIR);
    shuffle($files);
    $files = array_slice($files, 0, 1);
    foreach($files as $file)
        {
        return $file;
        }
    }

function rotate2()
    {
    $list = scandir(showRandomDir());
    $fileRotateList = array();
    $img = '';
    foreach($list as $fileRotate)
        {
        if (is_file(showRandomDir() . htmlspecialchars($fileRotate)))
            {
            $ext = strtolower(pathinfo($fileRotate, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
            if ($ext == 'gif' || $ext == 'jpeg' || $ext == 'jpg' || $ext == 'png')
                {
                $fileRotateList[] = $fileRotate;
                }
            }
        }

    if (count($fileRotateList) > 0)
        {
        $imageNumber = time() % count($fileRotateList);
        $img = showRandomDir() . urlencode($fileRotateList[$imageNumber]);
        }

    return $img;
    }
```

Comment: I thought random was a myth:  https://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/random_number.png

Answer (score 2):

At the beginning of your `rotate2()` function, you call `showRandomDir()` to get the contents of a random directory:

```
$list = scandir(showRandomDir());
```

But then at the end, you call `showRandomDir()` again, so you get a different random directory.
<sub>(Well, a *new* one, that's probably different, but could randomly be the same.)</sub>

```
$img = showRandomDir() . urlencode($fileRotateList[$imageNumber]);
```

You need to save the first call into a variable instead, and reuse that variable instead of calling `showRandomDir()` a second time.

```
$dir = showRandomDir();
$list = scandir($dir);
// ... the rest of the code in between
$img = $dir . urlencode($fileRotateList[$imageNumber]);
```

Comment: Okay, but now the output is with the image name -> images/portfolio/randomDir/

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what you mean by that. Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: Sorry, its not showing the filename, its displaying only the random dir

Comment: Now its -> /images/portfolio/randomDir and it should be /images/portfolio/randomDir/randomimage.jpg

Comment: Did you get it now?

Comment: Yes, I understand now, but I'm not sure why that's happening yet. Sorry, I need to go make dinner, but I'll take another look at it after.